# How to create ObjectManager service with Symfony2?

Tags: symfony, service

At beginning, I used repository.

But, after some code reviews on github, I'm interesting to use ObjectManager (to alleviate controllers, and also by curiosity ^^).

The problem is I didn't see some good tutorial about it. Even tutorials I saw was to initialize a service by an object manager but not to create one.

In the FriendsOfSymfony github, we could see an example for that but I don't really understand how to initialize the service. I have this error "Cannot instantiate interface Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager" when I initialize my manager service like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
```

http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services/services-1.0.xsd">

```
<parameters>
    <parameter key="md_mechanical.entity.enginemanager.class">MD\MechanicalBundle\Entity\EngineManager</parameter>
</parameters>

<services>
    <service id="md_mechanical.enginemanager.default" class="%md_mechanical.entity.enginemanager.class%">
        <argument type="service" id="md_mechanical.object_manager" />
        <argument>%md_engine.engine.class%</argument>
    </service>

    <!-- The factory is configured in the DI extension class to support more Symfony versions -->
    <service id="md_mechanical.object_manager" class="Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager">
        <argument>%fos_user.model_manager_name%</argument>
    </service>
</services>
```

thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score -1):

`Cannot instantiate interface Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager` means you are trying to instantiate an interface, which is not possible.

You have to create an object which implements this interface, and define all functions

```
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager as ObjectManager;

class MyObjectManager implements ObjectManager
{
    public function __construct(/* some params here */)
    {
        // Construct your manager here
    }

    public function find($className, $id)
    {
        // Do stuff
    }

    public function persist($object)
    {
        // Do stuff
    }

    public function remove($object)
    {
        // Do stuff
    }

    public function merge($object)
    {
        // Do stuff
    }

    public function clear($objectName = null)
    {
        // Do stuff
    }

    public function detach($object)
    {
        // Do stuff
    }

    public function refresh($object)
    {
        // Do stuff
    }

    public function flush()
    {
        // Do stuff
    }

    public function getRepository($className)
    {
        // Do stuff
    }

    public function getClassMetadata($className)
    {
        // Do stuff
    }

    public function getMetadataFactory()
    {
        // Do stuff
    }

    public function initializeObject($obj)
    {
        // Do stuff
    }

    public function contains($object)
    {
        // Do stuff
    }
}
```

Then declare it as a service

```
<services>
    <service id="myObjectManager" class="%myObjectManager.class%">
        <argument>...</argument>
    </service>

    # Use your brand new object manager
    <service id="md_mechanical.enginemanager.default" class="%md_mechanical.entity.enginemanager.class%">
        <argument type="service" id="myObjectManager" />
        <argument>%md_engine.engine.class%</argument>
    </service>
</services>
```

You should have a look at `Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager` and `Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface`, it may help you.